# Python print vs Javascript console.log()

Tags: javascript, console.log

In Python:

```py
print [1,2], '\n', [3,4]
```

would print

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

In Javascript:

```
console.log([1,2],'\n',[3,4])
```

prints

```
[1,2] '\n' [3,4]
```

What is the equivalent Javascript statement to the above Python `print`?

Comment: What the JavaScript console outputs is implementation specific, but `console.log([1,2]+'\n'+[3,4])` might work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are sending three arguments to console.log

```
console.log([1,2],'\n',[3,4])
```

Because the first argument, `[1,2]` doesn't contain formatting elements (e.g. `%d`), each argument is passed through [util.inspect()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options). util.inspect is returning the string representation of `'\n'` which is not what you want. You want `'\n'` to be interpreted.

One solution is to concatenate all arguments into one string

```
> console.log([1,2]+'\n'+[3,4]);
1,2
3,4
```

Another is to use formatting elements as placeholders, which util.format will substitute with two array's converted values.

```
> console.log('%s\n%s', [1,2], [3,4]);
1,2
3,4
```

I assumed node.js here, but the result in Mozilla is identical.

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, just split it into multiple `console.log` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: print ([1,2], "\'\n'", [3,4])
Here backslash denotes that \n and ' ' shouldn't perform it's operation and print as it is. Use a \ before \n and ' '